# Why is `unstable_Profiler` not profiling on production mode?

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I have an issue with `unstable_Profiler` on my React-Native project that is ignoring onRender callback, but only in production mode. No errors, everything renders fine. I went by this article: https://itnext.io/react-native-profiler-43d131130c5c

I tested solution on dev mode (react-native run-android) and everything worked perfect. Production build of app is not working.
I tried recent versions of react and react-native, react-dom, schedule, scheduler, modify .babelrc but nothing worked for me.

```
import React, { unstable_Profiler as Profiler } from 'react';

const withProfiler = (profilerId) => (WrappedComponent) => {

  class ProfilerComponent extends React.Component {

    async logMeasurement(id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration) {
      // see output during DEV
      console.log({id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration});

      // also here is some logic to log durations in prod mode. (eg. logcat)
      // but it never happened. 
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Profiler id={profilerId} onRender={this.logMeasurement}>
          <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
        </Profiler>
      );
    }
  }

  return ProfilerComponent;
};

export default withProfiler;
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {
        "react-dom$": "react-dom/profiling",
        "scheduler/tracing": "scheduler/tracing-profiling"
      }
    }]
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-remove-console",
      ]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

package.json

```
 "react": "^16.8.1",
 "react-native": "^0.57.8",
 "react-dom": "16.8.1",
 "react-art": "16.8.1",
 "schedule": "^0.4.0",
 "scheduler": "^0.13.1",

 "@babel/core": "7.1.0",
 "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
 "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^7.2.0",
 "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.1",
 "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
 "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
 "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
 "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.3",
 "babel-plugin-transform-remove-console": "^6.9.4",
 "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.48.1",
```

Expected result is that `logMeasurement` method is running in production app.

---

### EDIT

I have invalid binding of `logMeasurement`. Here is how I fixed it.

```
logMeasurement = async (id, phase, actualDuration, baseDuration) => { ... }
```

However, it did't fix the issue. The callback is still not called.

Comment: Could it be relevant that you're not [binding `this.logMeasurement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)?

Comment: Thanks @Jacob for reply. I've fixed it in the code above but with not luck solving the issue. I've edited the post though.

Comment: Hi, @user 6547076. Did you ever find the solution? I'm stuck on the same issue. Doesn't work in Production mode.

Answer (score 0):

```
const logProfile = (
  id: string,
  phase: "mount" | "update",
  actualDuration: number,
  baseDuration: number,
  startTime: number,
  commitTime: number,
  interactions: Set<any>
) => {
  console.log("Profiling ID", id);
  console.log("Profiling phase", phase);
  console.log("Profiling actualDuration", actualDuration);
  console.log("Profiling baseDuration", baseDuration);
  console.log("Profiling startTime", startTime);
  console.log("Profiling commitTime", commitTime);
  console.log("Profiling interactions", interactions);
};

class Sample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
          <Profiler id="application" onRender={logProfile}>
              <div id="preload_hidden"></div>
          </Profiler>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't spaek english not well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to opt in at build time since it is experimental.

```
yarn build --profile
```

You can also add it to your webpack build on your prod js file ading an alias

```
'react-dom$': 'react-dom/profiling'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue. Apparently it was caused by having "-" in the "id".

Changing it from

```
<Profiler id="Main-Value-Circle" onRender={this.profilerCallback}>
```

to

```
<Profiler id="MainValueCircle" onRender={this.profilerCallback}>
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for `react-native`

You can capture profiling information with the `<Profiler>` component in `release` builds by aliasing imports in the babel configuration

##### babel.config.js

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const config = {
    presets: [require('metro-react-native-babel-preset')],
    plugins: [],
};

/* When REACT_ENABLE_RELEASE_PROFILE is set we add these aliases 
 * to also capture React.Profiler metrics in release builds */
if (process.env.REACT_ENABLE_RELEASE_PROFILE) {
    const path = require('path');

    const profilingRenderer = path.resolve(
        __dirname,
        './node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Renderer/implementations/ReactNativeRenderer-profiling',
    );

    config.plugins.push(['module-resolver', {
        root: ['./'],
        alias: {
            'ReactNativeRenderer-prod': profilingRenderer,
            'scheduler/tracing': 'scheduler/tracing-profiling',
        },
    }]);
}

module.exports = config;
```

This would enable the `onRender` callback to work in production/release bundles as well

Profiling is disabled in release by default, because it adds some overhead
that's why it's preferable to only enable it conditionally like the above example

You can set this variable in a number of ways - before running the script, or as part of `.env` config

##### In `package.json`

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "profile:android": "REACT_ENABLE_RELEASE_PROFILE=true npm run android",
    "profile:ios": "REACT_ENABLE_RELEASE_PROFILE=true npm run ios"
  }
}
```

##### Or in `.env`

```sh
REACT_ENABLE_RELEASE_PROFILE=true
```